# Entity Frame work Edm Function on scalar valued function

Tags: entity-framework, user-defined-functions, sql-function

I have read and tried everything described in [this link](http://www.seventy-3.com/scalar-functions-and-ef-database-first/) to make this code run but I failed. It says "cannot be translated into a LINQ to Entities store expression."

MyDb is my MsSql database

GetDistance is my scalar-valued function returns as decimal

MyDbEntities as entity

MyDbModel as e.f. db model

here is my edmx file

```
<Function Name="GetDistance" ReturnType="decimal" Aggregate="false" BuiltIn="false" NiladicFunction="false" IsComposable="true" ParameterTypeSemantics="AllowImplicitConversion" Schema="dbo">
          <Parameter Name="lat1" Type="decimal" Mode="In" />
          <Parameter Name="lon1" Type="decimal" Mode="In" />
          <Parameter Name="lat2" Type="decimal" Mode="In" />
          <Parameter Name="lon2" Type="decimal" Mode="In" />
        </Function>
```

This is my Edm function (partial class of MyDbEntites)

```
[EdmFunction("MyDbModel.Store", "GetDistance")]
public static decimal GetDistance(decimal lat1, decimal lon1, decimal lat2, decimal lon2)
{
    throw new NotSupportedException("Direct calls not supported");
}
```

And here is my query

```
var query = (from city in context.TableCity
                             where
                                 city.IsActive
                             select new
                                 {                                         
                                     Distance = MyDbEntities.GetDistance(0, 0, city.Latitude, city.Longitude)
                                 });
```

Thank you